# uploadifive remove filename extension

Tags: jquery

how can i remove the file name extsion on uploadifive, i don't want to touch in the core of the plugin, i'm just need something like this.

> FROM: 'some pic description.jpg' TO: 'some pic'

i can't overrideEvent the first function that throw the html in the queue so i be able to regex the filename. i've try to use this:

```
'overrideEvents' : ['onUpload', 'onUploadComplete', 'onProgress'],
```

still can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

i've found the answer :)

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/truncatelength/

it does all the work for u!